# Force an application to run under specific .NET runtime version?

Tags: .net

I have .NET 2.0 runtime installed, then I installed the .NET 4.0 runtime, so I have both.  When I run a .NET app, is there a way to force which runtime will be used?

**Edit/Clarification:**  I meant w/o regards to how the application was built.  I am under the assumption that the .NET 4.0 runtime can run a .NET program compiled 5 years ago that targeted the 2.0 runtime (oldprogram.exe).  So now I am on a machine with both runtimes, either of which *could* handle oldprogram.exe.  Which runtime is chosen?  Can I influence which runtime is chosen?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, use the [`<supportedRuntime>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/startup/supportedruntime-element) element in the .exe.config file.  For example:

```
<configuration>
   <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
   </startup>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 6):

Take a look: [Configuring Assembly Binding Redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/433ysdt1.aspx)

> By default, applications use the set of .NET Framework assemblies that shipped with the runtime version used to compile the application. You can use the appliesTo attribute on the `<assemblyBinding>` element in an application configuration file to redirect assembly binding references to a specific version of the .NET Framework assemblies. This optional attribute uses a .NET Framework version number to indicate which version it applies to. If no appliesTo attribute is specified, the `<assemblyBinding>` element applies to all versions of the .NET Framework.

Comment: +1, this is the right answer if the program has already been built.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a list of MSDN reference to target specific .NET Framework version for VS.NET projects:

[How to: Target a Specific .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx)

Visual Studio 2010
[How to: Target a Specific .NET Framework Version or Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202%28VS.100%29.aspx)