# Restricting Powershell Commands by Version

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a Powershell script (on a Win10 machine) that needs to be backward-compatible all the way to Win7 machines - which shipped with Powershell Version 2.0.  I'd like to restrict my command set in the ISE to only those commands available in 2.0, or throw an error if I stray outside that version or something while I'm writing the script - is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: I don't know of a means to configure ISE that way, but you can at least test your script against version 2 of the command line, by running `powershell -version 2`.

Comment: See [Start PowerShell ISE with the 2.0 runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35705076)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there's a way in the ISE (I think not), but you can start the prompt (console host) separately in 2.0 mode:

```
powershell.exe -Version 2.0
```

You could use this in conjunction with ISE by editing and saving the script in ISE, then executing it in the console host. Not ideal, but not too bad of a workaround.

Comment: That'll work!  I'll use the console host to verify that the commands I want to use exist before I use them in ISE.

Answer (score 2):

```
Set-StrictMode -Version 2.0
```

[MSDN Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode?view=powershell-6)

-Version 2.0

- Prevents use of variables that have not been initialized (think
  Option Explicit in VBScript)
- Cannot call non-existent properties on
  objects
- Disallows calling a function like a method, for example,
  Do-Something(1 2)
- Prohibits creating variables without a name

Note, you can use it to restrict some functions for specific methods.

About the commandlets. Here no any solutions.

I saggest you to check every commandlet by using Get-Help. There you can get version in description.

Example:

```
Get-Help -Name "Invoke-RestMethod"
```

In answer:
...
This cmdlet was introduced in Windows PowerShell 3.0.
...

Answer (score -1):

You can also include the requires directive at the top of the script itself.

`#requires -version 5`

Use the correct number for the version your script requires, 2, 3, 4, etc. This will ensure it works in the ISE.

Comment: This does not do what the poster asked. It will not restrict the commands available to only those of a certain (maximum) version, it just doesn't allow the script to execute unless a specific _minimum_ version is available.